Issue "Invoke-Command & Get-Content with large files"
this is my first post because i can't find a solution and i don't understand whats wrong...
I have a simple script which should read a large logfile on a client with get-content in an invoke-command.
$getcontent = Get-Content $_.FullName
If I execute the get-content directly on the client, it takes less than 20 seconds and the logfile has been read into a variable.
If I execute the same command via an invoke, it takes 2 minutes(2).
$test = invoke-command -ComputerName "computername" -ScriptBlock{
    Get-ChildItem "g:\test*.log" -Filter *.log |
            Foreach-Object {
                $getcontent = Get-Content $_.FullName
                $linenumber = 0
                foreach($line in $getcontent){
                    $linenumber += 1
                    if($line.Contains("Received barcode: ")){   
                        $upc = ($line -split "Received barcode: ")[1]
                        if($upcssr.Length -le 13){
                            $checkupcssr += $upcssr 
                            #and i need to do more stuff here...
                        }
                }
        }
}
return $checkupcssr
}

any idea why?

You executing this invoke command on a remote computer?

yes i do - but you can try it on your own computer with invoke as well - same issue

I'm not following your use case. If you are executing remotely, is this some kind of remote shell or remote desktop? What are you trying to do? Why are you using invoke-command if you can execute it without invoke-command? If you are reading contents on a remote computer, do you need to transfer it to the new computer? I'm not even sure what would be the point of a "large file" where you just read the contents .... large files by definition aren't the kind of files you want to scroll through in a terminal.

i have around 500 clients where i need to check that log file every day. i know there are other possibilitys but i thought this should work because he is doing the invoke command directly on the system. i checked the network traffic and this is around 50 kb when i start the invoke command ... if i do a get-content with the network drive it's going up to 10 mb ... so this is a little bit wired

I need to check that log file every day check how? I see you using the get-content command but you aren't doing anything with the content you get.

this is just an example how you can reproduce it on your end. only the get-content taking that long...

It will be more efficient to transport a big single string than a million of little strings so try doing $test = get-content "G:\test.log" -Raw (note the -Raw, it's important)

What do you do with $test after that? Maybe you can pipe get-content to something else that narrows it down first.

Okay - i understand the issue now.
the problem is that i don't want to return the string to the server i need to check each line .... please check my post - i modfied it.

You never defined $upcssr and $checkupcssr in your script block.. so what are you actually trying to return from there? Can you [edit] your post and show us some of the content of the log files?

You can improve your script's performance by returning a single string from it, you need to consider that Get-Content by itself, without -Raw is already inefficient as it will wrap each line in a PSObject and then will attach properties to each line (PSPath, PSParentPath, PSChildName, etc). Then you need to consider that Invoke-Command will also do something similar, for each line it will attach more properties (PSComputerName, RunspaceId, PSShowComputerName, etc) making it even more inefficient. Then you need to consider the cost of transporting these object, it is more efficient to transport a single big string than a thousand little strings, so what you can do is:
$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName 'computername' -ScriptBlock {
    [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new().
        AppendLine("$(Get-Date) vor").
        Append((Get-Content 'G:\test.log' -Raw)).
        AppendLine("$(Get-Date) nach").
        ToString()
}

Creating a single string should more efficient in this case, then if you need to convert it into an array locally you can use -split, i.e.:
$stringArray = $result -split '\r?\n'
$stringArray[0]  # start time, result of `"$(Get-Date) vor"`
$stringArray[-1] # end time, result of `"$(Get-Date) nach"`


I would use a pipeline instead of setting a variable to the whole file. I assume upc and upcssr are the same thing, although $linenumber is unused. "+=" will be slower with large lists. I had to fix the indenting. With [pscustomobject], you'll get the pscomputername too.
# script.ps1
# 'Received barcode: 1' | set-content ~\documents\test1.log
Get-ChildItem test*.log -Filter *.log |
    Foreach-Object {
        $linenumber = 0
        $name = $_.name
        Get-Content $_.FullName | 
        foreach-object {
            $line = $_
            $linenumber += 1
            if($line.Contains('Received barcode: ')){   
                $upc = ($line -split 'Received barcode: ')[1]
                if($upc.Length -le 13){
                    [pscustomobject]@{upc = $upc; linenumber = $linenumber; 
                      name = $name} 
                    #and i need to do more stuff here...
                }
            }
        }
    }

# elevated prompt
invoke-command localhost,localhost,localhost script.ps1 | ft

upc linenumber name      PSComputerName RunspaceId
--- ---------- ----      -------------- ----------
1            1 test1.log localhost      7300de17-143c-4edf-89a5-d7554c9516f9
1            1 test1.log localhost      af0e217a-5eec-4940-9230-9e1107ca2edb
1            1 test1.log localhost      e97621ac-de08-44a7-a618-022443bf9ec4


My guess is that you want to loop over these log files in search of a certain string the fastest way possible and collect a workable result of all lines where the Received Barcode is a string of 13 or less characters.
In that case, I would use switch rather than Get-Content.
At the moment, your code is only outputting an array of these barcode strings, but you can extend on this by outputting objects instead.
Below shows you how you can do that.
$computers = 'pc01', 'pc02', 'pc03'  # the list of computers to probe

$result = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computers -ScriptBlock {
    foreach ($file in (Get-ChildItem "g:\test*.log" -Filter '*.log' -File)) {
        # loop through each file line by line fast
        switch -Regex -File ($file.FullName) {
            'Received barcode:' {
                $upc = ($_ -split 'Received barcode:\s+', 2)[-1].Trim()  # get the last part
                if ($upc.Length -le 13) {
                    # output an object that gets collected in variable $result
                    [PsCustomObject]@{
                        ComputerName = $env:COMPUTERNAME
                        File         = $file.FullName
                        Barcode      = $upc
                    }
                    # do whatever you need to do next, but don't output anything that might pollute the result
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

# remove the extra properties PowerShell added
$result = $result | Select-Object * -ExcludeProperty PS*, RunspaceId

# finally, display the result on screen
$result | Format-Table -AutoSize

# and/or save it as CSV file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\BarcodeCheck.csv' -NoTypeInformation -UseCulture

